# Consequence of the post auto incrementer off?

Tags: id

I'm moving a site with specific post IDs. If I programatically make a post with postID "4", and the autoincrementer is at "3", what are the consequences? Would it just skip to "5", overwrite 4, or blow up?

Comment: WordPress doesn't increment the post ID. The MySQL database does. So this is more of a generic MySQL question. But my question would be, why do you need to do this? If you find yourself relying on the post ID for something user-facing, and require particular numbers, then the post ID shouldn't be the number to use.

Comment: I'm moving a site from a custom CMS to WordPress, and I have to preserve the post IDs because of internal linking.